# Is there an IDE shortcut to make a Maven Dependency version property driven?

Tags: maven, ide, maven-2, keyboard-shortcuts, pom.xml

I admit this sounds insane. Can you not read the documentation or look it up?

So I'm refactoring a legacy project and I'm simply appalled that the dependency versions are hardcoded and not property driven. The latter:

- Aids readability of the `pom.xml`
- Upgrading the dependencies is usually easy
- You can refer property versions in parent/child submodules

So, basically. Turn below

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.a.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>A1</artifactId>
        <version>1.33</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.a.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>A2</artifactId>
        <version>1.34</version>
    </dependency>
   .....
```

into

```xml
    <properties>
      <A1.version>1.33</A1.version>
      <A2.version>1.34</A2.version>
    </properties>
    
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.a.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>A1</artifactId>
        <version>${A1.version}</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.a.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>A2</artifactId>
        <version>${A2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

P.S Don't bother with Regex.

Comment: If you define the dependencies in the dependencyManagement you don't need to use properties in your child modules...

Comment: That's not always feasible. Think single module projects. Besides, even in the dependency management section, you would want them to be property driven which again circles back to the original question.

Comment: In the end it's a manual task... so you have to clean up that project...

Comment: I agree. Thanks for weighing in.